# Bazel build on cycle in dependency graph error

Tags: java, tensorflow, gradle, build-process, bazel

I am doing a bazel build for my project,i created a java_library rule and used at different places. but I am having this cycle in dependency graph:

```
  ERROR: /Users/git/.../BUILD:11:1: java_library rule //B: cycle in dependency graph:
        //A.class
    .-> //B.class
    |   //C.class
    |   //D.class
    `-- //B.class
This cycle occurred because of a configuration option
```

This is because class B have method need call class D,  and class D is also calling class B several times. can i break this cycle, i can not remove remove B from any of BUILD files

Comment: give a try by having one more java_library with name "intermediate_B" have same arguments as java_library "B", means have two targets for "B" source code. and make java_library "D" depend on "intermediate_B". for the dependent targets of "D", you may have to include "B" explicitly and do not add "intermediate_B" in "exports" section for "D".

Comment: hello @Bhavik thanks a lot for your help,  can you give me more info on this: I will create a new java_library with name "intermediate_B" have same arguments as java_library "B", how can I do "C" and "D" dependent targets etc

Comment: hello @Bhavik can you make more clear on this:  make java_library "D" depend on "intermediate_B". for the dependent targets of "D", you may have to include "B" explicitly and do not add "intermediate_B" in "exports" section for "D".